# Skip an event from source observable if a new event from a given observable was received in a given time interval

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to write a method on UIView extension, which will observe long press on a given view. I know it can be done using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, but I really want to figure out the question and do it this way.

I tried to use takeUntil operator, but it completes an observable, but I need to skip the value and receive further events.

The question can be also transformed to: *How to omit `completed` event and keep receiving further events?*

```
func observeLongPress(with minimumPressDuration: Double = 1) -> 
  Observable<Void> {

    let touchesBeganEvent = rx.methodInvoked(#selector(touchesBegan))
    let touchesEndedEvents = [#selector(touchesEnded), #selector(touchesCancelled)]
        .map(rx.methodInvoked)
    let touchesEndedEvent = Observable.merge(touchesEndedEvents)
    return touchesBeganEvent
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .delay(minimumPressDuration, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .takeUntil(touchesEndedEvent)
        .map { _ in }
}
```

This will work, but will complete the whole sequence (as it intended to do).

The answer if floating around (as it always do), but after a few hours I decided to ask. :)

### Update

The floating answer just flew inside (~15 mins for doing so), but I'm still interested in answer, because maybe there's something that I'm missing here.

```
    func observeLongPress(with minimumPressDuration: Double = 1) -> Observable<Void> {
          let touchesBeganEvent = rx.methodInvoked(#selector(touchesBegan))
          let touchesEndedEvents = [#selector(touchesEnded), #selector(touchesCancelled)]
            .map(rx.methodInvoked)
          let touchesEndedEvent = Observable.merge(touchesEndedEvents)

          return touchesBeganEvent
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .flatMapLatest { _ -> Observable<Void> in
              return Observable.just(())
                .delay(minimumPressDuration, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                .takeUntil(touchesEndedEvent)
                .void()
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Updated code won't work. Even if you don't emit the completed event out of the function, it still got emitted from the `takeUntil` and therefore that operator won't emit any more values.

That said, this idea can be accomplished. Since you said you want to learn, I'll talk through my entire thought process while writing this.

First let's outline our inputs and outputs. For inputs we have two Observables, and a duration, and whenever we are dealing with duration we need a scheduler. For outputs we only have a single Observable.

So the function declaration looks like this:

```
func filterDuration(first: Observable<Void>, second: Observable<Void>, duration: TimeInterval, scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<Void> {
    // code goes here.
}
```

We are going to be comparing the time that the two observables fire so we have to track that:

```
let firstTime = first.map { scheduler.now }
let secondTime = second.map { scheduler.now }
```

And since we are comparing them, we have to combine them somehow. We could use `merge`, `combineLatest`, or `zip`...

- `combineLatest` will fire whenever either Observable fires and will give us the latest values from both observables.
- `zip` will mate, 1 for 1, events from both observables. This sounds intriguing, but would break down if one of the observables fires more often than the other so it seems a bit brittle.
- `merge` will fire when either of them fire, so we would need to track which one fired somehow (probably with an enum.)

Let's use `combineLatest`:

```
Observable.combineLatest(firstTime, secondTime)
```

That will give us an `Observable<(RxTime, RxTime)>` so now we can map over our two times and compare them. The goal here is to return a `Bool` that is true if the second time is greater than the first time by more than `duration`.

```
    .map { arg -> Bool in
        let (first, second) = arg
        let tickDuration = second.timeIntervalSince(first)
        return duration <= tickDuration
    }
```

Now the above will fire every time either of the two inputs fire, but we only care about the events that emit `true`. That calls for `filter`.

```
.filter { $0 } // since the wrapped value is a Bool, this will accomplish our goal.
```

Now our chain is emitting Bools which will always be true but we want a Void. How about we just throw away the value.

```
.map { _ in }
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
func filterDuration(first: Observable<Void>, second: Observable<Void>, duration: TimeInterval, scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<Void> {

    let firstTime = first.map { scheduler.now }
    let secondTime = second.map { scheduler.now }

    return Observable.combineLatest(firstTime, secondTime)
        .map { arg -> Bool in
            let (first, second) = arg
            let tickDuration = second.timeIntervalSince(first)
            return duration <= tickDuration
        }
        .filter { $0 }
        .map { _ in }
}
```

The above isolates our logic and is, not incidentally, easy to test with RxTests. Now we can wrap it up into a UIView (that would be hard to test.)

```
func observeLongPress(with minimumPressDuration: Double = 1) -> Observable<Void> {

    let touchesBeganEvent = rx.methodInvoked(#selector(touchesBegan)).map { _ in }
    let touchesEndedEvents = [#selector(touchesEnded), #selector(touchesCancelled)]
        .map(rx.methodInvoked)
    let touchesEndedEvent = Observable.merge(touchesEndedEvents).map { _ in }
    return filterDuration(first: touchesBeganEvent, second: touchesEndedEvent, duration: minimumPressDuration, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
}
```

There you go. One custom operator.

Comment: Now that the `filterDuration` function exists, we can have fun making it generic so we can pass any type Observable to it. I'll leave that as an exercise. And be sure to check out RxTests!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! You said the code in update won't work, but actually it does. _takeUntil_ completes the sequence, but only the wrapped one, so the result is correct and we receive further events until disposal. I like your approach, but it only works when the second Observable produces an event, since `combineLatest` need each observable to produce at least one item. I would like to accept this answer if you'd correct it.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. I guessed at the context. To address your comment: First, if you have `observeLongPress` in a flatMap, then yes you would continue to receive events, but in that case there's no need to remove the `completed` event (and in fact it would be a bad idea.) Second, the point of the `filterDuration` function is that it doesn't emit a next event unless the second observable emits one, so the fact that `combineLatest` doesn't emit `next` unless the second observable emits one isn't a bug, it's a feature. That said, I'm glad you found a solution that's to your liking.